# Sonar 5.6 - How to ignore some files from undocumented API metric?

Tags: documentation, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have documentation issues ignored on some of my files. For instance:

```
# Ignore all undocumented API issues on test headers
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.noapitest.ruleKey=cxx:UndocumentedApi
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.noapitest.resourceKey=test/include/*
```

This works well, the issues are not generated. However, I was wondering if it was also possible to exclude them from the undocumented API metric ? Currently they are showing as undocumented and making the metric completely useless for me.

I'm using Sonar 5.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nope](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/sonarqube/pTaeV2yLpU8). All of the exclusion options are [fully documented](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) and obvious in the UI.